# clearing text box elements in perl tk

Tags: perltk

I am building a GUI in Perl tk and I have made a reset button which is supposed to clear elements of a text box:

```
use Tk;
use Tk::Text ;
............
sub reset9 {
    $txt2-> delete('1.0','end');
}
```

This is giving an error saying it cannot call method Delete on an undefined value. I have checked for all syntax errors and I am using Strawberry Perl for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your subroutine does not know what $txt2 is.  If $txt2 was defined inside another subroutine add the word "our" before it (instead of using my).

i.e.

```
our $txt2 = ...
```

That should do the trick for you

Answer (score 0):

You may try : 
$txt2-> delete('0.0','end');